# WP Query to set post thumbnail for existing old posts

Tags: post-thumbnails

I found this PHP code that will set the first attached image as the post thumbnail. https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/23768

Is it possible to loop through old posts that have attachments using WP_Query() to set the post thumbnail for old posts? If the post has more than 1 attachement, I'd like to set the first attachment as the post thumbnail.

I'd like to do this only once to get everything up to date, then I can incorporate the PHP code from the answer above to modify new posts going forward.

As requested, here is the code from the aforementioned linked answer.

```
function myprefix_main_image() {
$attachments = get_children( 'post_parent='.$post->ID.'&post_type=attachment&post_mime_type=image&order=desc' );
if( $attachments ) {
    $keys = array_reverse( $attachments );
    set_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, $keys[0]->ID );
};
```

}

Comment: Much better. :) Now if you'll add the relevant code from the other question directly to your question, rather than linking the question, we'll have something to work with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first step is to loop through all the posts:

```
$wpse87964query = new WP_Query();
```

Now, that will get *all* the posts; but we're only interested in posts that don't have a featured image set. WordPress stores the featured image via a post custom meta field: `_thumbnail_id`; so, [we can use that in a **meta query**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters), to get only the posts that *don't* have a set featured image:

```
$wpse87964query_args = array(
    'nopaging' => true,
    meta_query( array(
        array(
            'key' => '_thumbnail_id',
            'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'
        )
    ) )
)
$wpse87964query = new WP_Query( wpse87964query_args );
```

Now, set up the loop:

```
if ( $wpse87964query->have_posts() ) : while ( $wpse87964query->have_posts() ) : $wpse87964query->the_post();

// CODE WILL GO HERE

endwhile; endif;
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Now, query for attachments:

```
$attachments = get_children( 'post_parent=' . get_the_ID() . '&post_type=attachment&post_mime_type=image&order=desc' );
if( $attachments ) {
    $keys = array_reverse( $attachments );
    set_post_thumbnail( get_the_ID(), $keys[0]->ID );
};
```

Now wrap the whole thing inside a function, so you can call it somewhere, or hook it into something:

```
function wpse87964_set_post_thumbnails() {

    // Query args
    $wpse87964query_args = array(
        'nopaging' => true,
        meta_query( array(
            array(
                'key' => '_thumbnail_id',
                'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'
            )
        ) )
    )
    // Run query
    $wpse87964query = new WP_Query( wpse87964query_args );

    // Open query loop
    if ( $wpse87964query->have_posts() ) : while ( $wpse87964query->have_posts() ) : $wpse87964query->the_post();

        // Query post attachments
        $attachments = get_children( 'post_parent=' . get_the_ID() . '&post_type=attachment&post_mime_type=image&order=desc' );
        if( $attachments ) {
            $keys = array_reverse( $attachments );
            set_post_thumbnail( get_the_ID(), $keys[0]->ID );
        };

    // Close query loop
    endwhile; endif;
    wp_reset_postdata();

}
```

You can improve this function, by stepping through the posts in batches, or by defining your own post custom meta to query against, so that you only process each post once, etc.

Comment: is there a way to use images of posts like e.g. `<img alt="" src="../pic/logos/rete2.gif" />` so not attached pictures